# MultiCombo Boxes that affect eachother c#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, combobox

So say I have three comboboxes (cmb1,cmb2,cmb3) and each has three items within it (a,b,c). If I choose an item in cmb1 say "a" then I use cmb2 or cmb3 it will only have b and c left in it and if I unselect a then it will be re-added back in to the list. **How do I remove and add it back in succesfully?**

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add("a");
        list.Add("b");
        list.Add("c");

        foreach (string i in list)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
            comboBox2.Items.Add(i);
            comboBox3.Items.Add(i);
        }//adds list items to combo boxes
    }

    private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1.Text == list[0].ToString())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Remove(list[0]);
            comboBox3.Items.Remove(list[0]);
        }// removes item from other lists if chosen from one

        if (comboBox1.Text == list[1].ToString())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Remove(list[1]);
            comboBox3.Items.Remove(list[1]);
        }

        if (comboBox1.Text == list[2].ToString())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Remove(list[2]);
            comboBox3.Items.Remove(list[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-adding at the same index is hard if you have removed several items. It gets easier if you have a sort order. If you don't you need to store a copy of the original order. You can Add or Insert Items then as needed.

Comment: Is there anyway I can just hide it from the other combo boxes?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.AddRange(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });

    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
    comboBox2.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
    comboBox3.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
}
```

Using `comboBox1` `SelectionChangeCommitted` event and a field to store the  select item, add and remove the items in the other ComboBoxes:

```
private int PreviousSelectedIndex = -1;

private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
    if (PreviousSelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Insert(PreviousSelectedIndex, comboBox1.Items[PreviousSelectedIndex]);
        comboBox3.Items.Insert(PreviousSelectedIndex, comboBox1.Items[PreviousSelectedIndex]);
    }

    comboBox2.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    comboBox3.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    PreviousSelectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```